# USPTO examiner audience

Tags: examiner

At what education level should I assume of the examiner.   Is suspect that if I KISS it that will only help: is this correct?  In not,  Why?

I am interested in applying for a utility patent with a device and method to electronically measure events.

Comment: I don't think kissing the examiner will help. What's KISS?

Comment: @DonQuiKong "[Keep it simple, stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)". Maybe a culturally-specific reference.

Comment: @Maca I'm no native speaker, hadn't heard it. @ op: someone knowing the basics should be able to grasp it on the first try and someone with deep understanding should still learn something about your invention without dying from boredom.

Answer (score 2):

None. The examiner is not the person you should have in mind when determining how you explain your invention.

The “person skilled in the art“ must be able to make/build your invention from the description. While the person skilled in the art is not a real person, they can be assumed to have a relevant background both educational and working experience.

The examiner will like you if your patent description is clear, precise and structured, but that's beside the point. If the examiner or a judge doesn't understand something in your description you must be able to provide literature (standard books used in universities for teaching, dictionaries and similar, no papers or research) that explains it. If you can't, it's not disclosed in sufficient detail.

The person skilled in the art basically knows what the relevant standard literature teaches and uses that to interpret your description and the prior art.